# How to sum spreadsheet cells under the condition of containing the character "/"

Tags: google-sheets

I want to write an Array to sum a row if the cells contain a certain symbol. For example, I want a sum from `A1:A10` if the cell contains "/".

Answer (score 4):

Summing the cells in one column under condition that cells in another column contain "/" does not require an arrayformula. It can be done with

```
=sumifs(A1:A10, B1:B10, "*/*")
```

where A1:A10 is the sum range, B1:B10 is the condition range, and `*/*` is a pattern that says "contains /" because an asterisk matches any group of symbols.

One can also use `sumif` for this purpose, but since `sumifs` can do everything `sumif`  does, and more, I prefer to stick to `sumifs`.